Questions about disk allocation
After I uninstalled /dev/nvmeon1p1 from /boot and executed the command dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1p1, I used the mount command to mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 to /mnt, can I ask if this /mnt can be accessed normally and can write data?
Another question I have is whether the dd command after using zero fill to erase partition data will empty the filesystem metadata of that partition, making it inaccessible after the partition is remounted?

Hello DarcyWalter. The order of commands can't have worked unless there was something else you've ommitted. The dd command, as shown here, is a very inefficient way of erasing a partition. After running this there will have been no filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p1 so there is no way you could have successfully executed mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt. Please check what you really ran and edit your question accordingly
